# Angular 2 - Webpack 2 - template-loader not working with templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, webpack, ts-loader

I've created a minimal webpack example for my Application and I try to use templateUrl with "./file.name.html" to get compiled. But the only thing my Application shows is the name of the templateUrl "./file.name.html" on my Index page. The applications seems to work, because there are no errors in the console and the

```
<app>... Loading </app>
```

is not shown any more. Before I tried to use webpack I've used systemJs and My App was working very well. So I don't think its a app problem.

my starting file name is boot.ts

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import "zone.js/dist/zone";

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

the app.component definition looks like

```
.... Imports

@Component({
    selector: 'sxp-app',
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent { ... }
```

my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./App/boot.ts",
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './Scripts/dist'),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
             {
                 test: /\.ts$/,
                 loader: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
             },
             {
                test: /\.html$/, 
                loader: 'raw-loader'
             }
        ]
    }
};
```

the package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "~3.2.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26",
    "ui-router-ng2": "1.0.0-beta.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.51",
    "@types/requirejs": "2.3.1",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "css-loader": "0.26.0",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.4.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "typings": "2.0.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.27",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.12",
    "webpack-merge": "0.17.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

and the tsconfig.json

```
 {
   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "commonjs",
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "removeComments": false,
     "noImplicitAny": false,
     "types": [
       "node" 
     ]
   },
   "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
     "useWebpackText": true
   },
  "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "dist",
       "typings/main",
       "typings/index.d.ts"
     ],
     "compileOnSave": true
   }
```

I am using Ui-router and I see that the right url is loaded, but its only showing the template Filenames like "./appHeader.component.html" but no Template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found my Problem!

don't use ES6 quotation marks like

```
templateUrl: \`./app.component.html`
```

this will render just "./app.component.html" in your app

Use normal quotation marks like the following:

```
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
```

Comment: The reason doing this breaks it is that a regular expression is used by the `angular2-template-loader` package. You can look in `node_modules\angular2-template-loader` and view the `index.js` file which contains the regexes.

Comment: I am looking at the documentation and the after statement shows  @Component({
  selector: 'awesome-button',
  template: require('./button.template.html'),
  styles: [require('./button.style.css')]
}).        I see the keep url option but it doesn't say anything about relative path.  Did you have to do any extra work besides adding the loader with awesome-typescript-loader?

Comment: @Winnemucca no require required with the newest template loader and webpack

Answer (score 7):

Another reason this won't work is if you have already compiled `.js` files correspoding to your `.ts` file. Some IDEs will create these by themselves when you save or compile.

This has the effect that when a 'module' is requested it first finds the `.js` file and doesn't process the `.ts` file at all - so it won't go through this 'chain'.

Edit your `.csproj` file and add this as a new property group (search first that it doesn't already exist). This will prevent Visual Studio from auto-generating a `.js` file on save.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Make sure to delete all generated `.js` and `.js.map` files that have a corresponding `.ts` file under your `ClientApp` folder (components etc.). Check into source control / backup first just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `template: require("./app.component.html")` instead of `templateUrl:"..."` in order to make it work.

Webpack scans your files and searches for e.g. require(...) tags.

Comment: the documentation from "angular2-template-loader" https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader#how-does-it-work says that I can chain the normal TypeScript Loader and the templateloader works with m relative path informations. Also the Angular 2 documentation for Webpack shows it so, but I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: hm okay we always use the require statement in our apps.

Comment: Could you provide a Plunker maybe?

Comment: I will create a small example tonight and will upload it.

Comment: angular2-template-loader is supposed to convert to require right?